# Pandas does not raise KeyError for missing column with .drop_duplicates()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Something just happened with Pandas which makes me trust it a bit less, does anyone know why it behaves like this? Anyway, for this small example is easy to see, but for a larger dataframe, one would need to take care.. I almost made a mistake with something.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[34,12,78,84,26], "B":[54,87,35,81,87], "C":[56,78,0,14,13], "D":[0,87,72,87,14], "E":[78,12,31,0,34]}) 
>> df
```

[image]

Then, if you look for a column which isn't there:

```
df['b']
KeyError: 'b'
```

But -

```
df.drop_duplicates(['b', 'D'])
```

...runs without error, and finds the error in column D.

[image]

Actually, `df.drop_duplicates(['D'])` produces exactly the same result.

It has missed one duplicate row however has also missed one in column B because it has been misspelled. It doesn't warn you or raise an error.

Using Pandas 0.22.0 and Python 3.6.4.

`df.drop_duplicates(['B','D'])` just returns the original dataframe without dropping anything.  Am I missing something or is Pandas broken?

Comment: Have tested this myself with different Pandas and created an issue on GitHub. Pandas 19 is working fine but Pandas 22 has problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas version 0.20.3 python 3.6.

When I run this line of code:

```
df.drop_duplicates(['b', 'D'])
```

There is

> KeyError: 'b'

In your example is strange situation with row 4.

First

```
df.loc[4,'B'] = 87
```

After drop duplicate:

```
df.loc[4,'B'] = 82
```

It looks like you have some extra operation between this steps.

Comment: Thanks for testing it. At least yours behaves correctly.. I just ran exactly two lines of code from my question above in a fresh notebook, the df definition and `df.drop_duplicates(['b', 'D'])`. Here, `pd.__version__` gives '0.22.0' and `sys.version_info` gives `sys.version_info(major=3, minor=6, micro=4, releaselevel='final', serial=0)` ie 3.6.4